# multiple reference to primary key in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key

i trying to retrieve value by referencing primary key in multiple tables but unable to get the result.Here is the table

Density Table

```
 **de_id  density  color**
    1   21  red
    2   22  blue
    3   23  green
    4   24  yellow
    5   25  orange
```

Size Table

```
**si_id   length  breadth**
1        21     41
2        22     42
3        23     43
4        24     44
5        25     45
```

Order_de Table

```
**or_id  density    color  length breadth**
 1     1          2       3       4
 2     4          3       2       1
```

The query i am trying to work out is

```
  SELECT density.density,density.color,size.length,size.breadth,order_de.or_id from 
    density,size,order_de WHERE order_de.density=density.de_id and 
    order_de.color=density.de_id and order_de.length=size.si_id and 
    order_de.breadth=size.si_id  order by order_de.or_id asc
```

The desired result should be

```
density   color   length breadth  or_id
     21    blue      23    44       1
     24   green      22    41       2
```

But the query retrieves nothing.
Can any one help??

Comment: why this schema is not making sense to me? Is it common?

Comment: @Nishant: It made little sense to me either to store seemingly unrelated attributes (density, color) in the same table, especially with the same ID.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli it may be a table of chemical substance with it's density and color. But the way the data is needed to be extracted make my head spin. He want attribute from one table two rows. density 21 is not red and color blue is not the same as density of value 21. The way I think is: One row represents one item, and FK is just a pointer to it. Why would one want to mix attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the tables independently for each attribute: density, color, length and breadth. Also, don't use the implicit join style. I think that contributed to your confusion in producing this query.

```
SELECT d1.density, d2.color, s1.length, s2.breadth, o.or_id 
    FROM Order_de o
        INNER JOIN Density d1
            ON o.density = d1.de_id
        INNER JOIN Density d2
            ON o.color= d2.de_id
        INNER JOIN Size s1
            ON o.length = s1.si_id
        INNER JOIN Size s2
            ON o.breadth = s2.si_id
    ORDER BY o.or_id asc
```